# Suppress specific error/warning mesage in puppet?

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to suppress *specific* error messages when running a Puppet manifest?

The following snippet activates and starts iptables if the file /etc/sysconfig/iptables exists. It works fine, but "Check for iptables rulesfile" generates an error message that I would like to hide. I checked the (v2.7) docs the options of the exec resource type and Googled, but no luck.

```
cat init.pp
service { "iptables":
  enable  => true,
  ensure  => running,
  require => Exec["Check for iptables rulesfile"];
}

exec { "Check for iptables rulesfile":
  command => "/usr/bin/test -f /etc/sysconfig/iptables",
  returns => "0";
}

puppet apply --debug init.pp
...
err: /Stage[main]//Exec[Check for iptables rulesfile]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /usr/bin/test -f /etc/sysconfig/iptables returned 1 instead of one of [0] at init.pp:12
...
warning: /Stage[main]//Service[iptables]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

Any thoughts?

P.S. Yes, I'm aware this is not the 'right' way to manage firewall rules with Puppet.

Answer (score 1):

I gather that you want the iptables service to only be enabled and running if /etc/sysconfig/iptables exists.  One easy option would be to create a custom fact named iptables (or whatever tickles your fancy) and use that boolean to decide whether or not to execute the service block.  For example:

Create a custom fact in your module, in $module_name/lib/facter:

```
 Facter.add("iptables") do
   setcode do
     if Facter::Util::Resolution.exec('test -f /etc/sysconfig/iptables') then
       "true"
     else
       "false"
     end
   end
 end
```

Then, in your service block have something like this:

```
 if $::iptables == "true" {
   service { "iptables":
     enable  => true,
     ensure  => running,
   }
 }
```

This will only execute that service block if that file exists.  I think that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Boscoe sketches a very good solution.

Your hack might work as well, try with the [loglevel](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/metaparameter.html#loglevel) metaparameter.

```
exec { "Check for iptables rulesfile":
    command  => "/usr/bin/test -f /etc/sysconfig/iptables",
    loglevel => "debug",
    returns  => "0";
}
```

Note that the service resource **will** complain about failed dependencies.

Comment: Hi Felix. Thanks for your response, but this still produces an 'err' message.

Comment: Hi, interesting - even if you omit the `--debug` flag to `puppet apply`?